# Polynomial $U$ such that $ U^{"}-XU^{'}=0 $

Tags: polynomials

Let $U \in  \mathbb{R}  \left[ X \right] $.

What are the polynomial $U$ such that $ U^{"}-XU^{'}=0 $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $U$ has degree $n \geq 2$, then $U''$ has degree $n-2$, while $XU'$ is of degree $n$. Their difference cannot be $0$.

If $U$ has degree $1$, then $U'' = 0$, while $XU' \neq 0$, and their difference cannot be $0$.

If $U$ is a constant, then the equation is satisfied.